# Get effective executable filename

Tags: c#, windows-7, 64-bit, filesystems, redirect

A .NET application (managed) runs on Windows 7 64 bit. It is actually running on a 64 bit environment.

The application inspect running process (for example, calc.exe) which is located in *c:\windows\syswow64\calc.exe*.

So, why the function

```
Process.MainModule.Filename
```

returns *c:\windows\system32\calc.exe*? Is it possible to get the effective executable main module location, when is **unredirected** from SYSWOW64 directory?

---

What are possible workarounds? The quickest I wrote is the following snippet:

```
bool iWindows = pFilename.StartsWith(@"c:\windows\", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
bool iWindowsSystem32 = pFilename.StartsWith(@"c:\windows\system32\", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

if ((iWindows == true) || (iWindowsSystem32 == true)) {
    string pActualFileName;

    if (iWindowsSystem32 == true)
        pActualFileName = pFilename.Replace(@"c:\windows\system32\", @"c:\windows\syswow64\");
    else
        pActualFileName = pFilename.Replace(@"c:\windows\", @"c:\windows\syswow64\");
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743.aspx) before the usage of `Process.MainModule.Filename`. Verifying that the program are running on 64-bit operation system with [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139.aspx) or [Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx) (if you use .NET 4.0) before usage of [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743.aspx) is recommended.

**UPDATED**: I am sure that you have a small error in your code or the problem can be on .NET runtines which you have installed. I tested your problem with respect of the following test code

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Win64ProcesPath {
    class Program {
        static void Main (string[] args) {
            Process myProcess = new Process ();

            try {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "calc.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start ();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (1000);
                Console.WriteLine ("{0}", myProcess.MainModule.FileName);

                Process p = Process.GetProcessById (myProcess.Id);
                Console.WriteLine ("{0}", p.MainModule.FileName);

                //Process p32 = Process.GetProcessById (8048);
                //Console.WriteLine ("{0}", p32.MainModule.FileName);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 installed on Vindows 7 64-bit (x64). On Vindows 7 64-bit there are two version of `calc.exe`: one 32-bit under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\calc.exe` and another 64-bit under `C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe`. How can easy verify the files has different file size (776,192 and 918.528 bytes). If I compile the program as 64-bit program it starts `C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe` and `Process.GetProcessById(processId).MainModule.FileName` shows also correct file name. One can also use `Process.GetProcessById()` to get correct path of 32-bit version of calc.exe which are started separately (see commented lines). So 64-bit versin of this program has no problem in my envoronment.

If you do have 32-bit application you will be able to access to the full filesystem after the call of [Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743.aspx), but you will **not** be able to access the memory of 64-bit programs and `Process.MainModule` will throw the excepion `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` with the code `NativeErrorCode: 299` and the `Message: "A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process."` To be able to get the full filename of 64-bit application you should use API with get you results produced from a 64-bit operation system component (like WMI and so on). But it's already another probelm, because how you wrote your program is 64-bit program.

Comment: It doesn't work: GetLastError() == ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION (I think because application is a 64 bit executable).

Comment: Sorry could you describe the scenario more exact? Do you wrote a 64-bit .NET Assembly which are loaded from a process and you want know the full path name of the process? Do you wrote a 64-bit .NET application (EXE) and you try to examine a full path of an application which you started by short file name like "calc.exe"? Or your application is do 32-bit .NET application?

Comment: I wrote a 64-bit .NET application, which calls Process.GetProcessById(pid) to inspect running process (i.e.: calc.exe), which is 64-bit. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the assembly and then getting the assembly location, such as

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Comment: The underlying process is an external one, no the currently executing.